# MySQL query with date ranges returning no results

Tags: php, mysql, date, range

So I am doing this query from PHP, and here listerally the exact query string:

```
SELECT * FROM `pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets` WHERE 
`pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`.`username` = 'pdem' AND 
`pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`.`date` >= '2012-05-09' AND 
`pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`.`date` <= '2012-05-15' ORDER BY
`pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`.`date` ASC
```

It looks like it should be correct to me (more-or-less copying it from previous code I used that DOES work). But when I run the query, the results are empty.

If I change the query to not be a date range, but just a single day:

```
SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ...`date` = '2012-06-12' ....
```

it works just fine, returns the one result that it should.

I have tried using the between keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...`date` BETWEEN [start] [end]
```

but it still returns nothing...

Any ideas how to get this query to return a result?

**===ANSWER===**

When you go:

```
var curr_date = now.getDate();
var curr_month = now.getMonth();
var curr_year = now.getFullYear();
```

it returns the month - 1 for some reason. So if now's month is 6, now.getMonth() will return 5...Just need to add 1 in the query (wish I saw this sooner)

Comment: It may be that all 3 'AND' conditions are not satisfying any record, thats why results are empty.

Comment: could you provide what you get for ***SELECT * FROM `pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`***

Comment: Is there any user called `pdem` in your database? Also you forgot an `AND` in your `BETWEEN` query.

Comment: May be there are no results at all, anyways, what happens if you try, i.e. `"select * from ..... where date between '2012-05-09' and '2012-05-09' ORDER BY..."`

Comment: May be your month passed is wrong. One row is getting for '2012-06-12'. Check 
`pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`.`date` >= '2012-06-09' AND 
`pdem_timesheet`.`tblMasterTimesheets`.`date` <= '2012-06-15'

Comment: Also make sure that the `date` field is in fact of the correct date datatype, or else the comparison may fail. The fact that it works when using "=" but not using ">=" suggests this.

Comment: is the "date" column of the right type (e.g. 'date', not 'varchar')? Uh, StuckAtWork came before :)

Comment: According to your SQL you were using May (05). Make sure in your real SQL you're using June (06).

Comment: June 12, 2012 is not between '2012-05-09' and '2012-05-15' (those dates are both in May).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems to be working for me.

### See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fcb5/3).

***Query I have is***

```
SELECT * FROM tblMasterTimesheets
WHERE 
username='pdem'
AND
date >= '2012-05-09' AND
date <= '2012-05-15'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

***I assume, `username` is of type `varchar` and `date` is of type `timestamp` or `datetime`.***

Comment: I didn't realize until I saw it written out how you wrote it. When I got the month (var curr_month = now.getMonth();), it returned MONTH -1, so it was giving me 05, instead of 06

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Fahim Parkar, here is an example of your query working with the use of the BETWEEN syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fcb5/4

It sounds like your user pdem does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

1. There is in fact a result which should be returned when using your
   given criteria. Make sure the `DD-MM-YYYY` syntax is correct and make sure you know which month is which number (may is 05, june is 06)
2. That the datatype of the column `date` is of a date
       type, not a generic text/varchar type. You cannot compare varchar with >= like that (not the way you want, at least. Only works on date types)

As Fahim said, your code is correct. It must be something within the table which is causing your issues.

Comment: Actually, you can string compare dates written like that. Later dates are lexicographically greater than earlier ones.

Comment: Depends which syntax he's actually using, does it not? YYYY-MM-DD yes, but wouldn't DD-MM-YYYY depend on the day first?

Comment: You see the syntax in the question. Toadums is obviously using the standard syntax from ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: True. I suppose I was trying to cover all the bases, as his code was correct (what he showed) but was not working for him. Might also help anybody not using the standard syntax who comes across a similar situation.